# SWT: quick way of finding out whether a shell has child shells

Tags: swt

I could iterate over all shells reported by `display.getShells()` and check their parents. Is there an alternative to find out whether a shell has child shells (or get all child shells)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Shell.getShells()` should show you all descendant shells.  Is it not working?

Comment: Don't know why I missed this obvious method.